# CSS nested Div with position absolute?

Tags: html, css

Here is a reproduction of a far more complex case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:500px;top:200px;width:200px;background-color:red;";>
        AS HDSKLAJD KLASJD KLASJ DKLASJDKL JASKLD JKLAS JDKLASD AS HDSLAJD
        <p>
        sadas dasd sad asd sadas dasd sad asdsadas dasd sad asdsadas dasd sad asd
        </p>

        <div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:10px;background-color:green;";>
            CORNER
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is to have the div with the CORNER text at the 0,0 of the page. I KNOW I can simply change the DIV in the html to be outside the first DIV with absolute but I cannot do it since in the real case I am limited to a ContentPlaceHolder (ASP.NET). So, is it possible to have a DIV that is nested inside an other DIV with position absolute and to have its coordinate absolute to the page?

Comment: Given that you know the positioning of the "AS HDSKLAJD KLASJD KLASJ DKLASJDKL JASKLD JKLAS JDKLASD AS HDSLAJD" `<div>` element, couldn't you just position absolutely to compensate? `position:absolute;left:-500px;top:-200px;`

Comment: ... or could you replace the absolute positioning of the "AS HDSKLAJD KLASJD KLASJ DKLASJDKL JASKLD JKLAS JDKLASD AS HDSLAJD" `<div>` with margin/padding?

Comment: You'll find many people interested this topic over at Doctype (http://doctype.com/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So, is it possible to have a DIV that is nested inside an other DIV with position absolute and to have its coordinate absolute to the page?

Not absolute to the page, no. You can use negative `left` and `top` values to move the DIV outside the container - if the `left` and `top` coordinates of the container are fixed, you can achieve the effect that way - but the coordinates will always be relative to the container, never to the page.

**Edit:** There's `position:fixed` that *does* break out of the container (try changing it in your example, `left: 0px top: 0px` will place it in the top left corner of the page as you want it) but it has the obvious side-effect of being fixed on the viewport, not in the document - so it's useful only if no scrolling occurs in the body.

Comment: Actually thats not true. You can... see my answer for details.

Comment: @prodigitalson waiting for your answer!

Comment: Nice one Pekka, I need to check if I can use this position. In the real case, we are using a Third-Party library for drag-and-drop and I am not sure I can tell the component to change its position mode. I'll take a look and come back.

Comment: _"so it's useful only if no scrolling occurs in the body"_ is a very important note when using `position:fixed`!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this isn't the generalized solution you need, but you can change the absolute positioning of the outer `<div>` to margin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
    <div style="margin-left:500px;margin-top:200px;width:200px;background-color:red;";>
        AS HDSKLAJD KLASJD KLASJ DKLASJDKL JASKLD JKLAS JDKLASD AS HDSLAJD
        <p>
        sadas dasd sad asd sadas dasd sad asdsadas dasd sad asdsadas dasd sad asd
        </p>

        <div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:10px;background-color:green;";>
            CORNER
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When you do that the inner `<div>` will position itself absolutely within the `<body>` - its nearest ancestor with non-static positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates for abs positioning use the closest positioned parent box of the positioned element. So assuming that your div creating the corner(s) has no parent elements that are rel or abs positioned it will default up the chain to the html element which is at 0,0 of the viewport. The only problem here is this may be hard to accomplish depending on your layout. So while theoretically its possible it might not be practical. Its better to use position relative on the direct parent and then position with negative values.

Comment: @prodigitalson well, that's what I'm saying, isn't it? If you're inside an abs or rel positioned box, a child element can't "break out" and position itself relative to the grandparent. I'm disappointed man, I was waiting for a magnificent trick :)

Comment: oops yeah thats my bad... I didnt notice he had abs on the parent. Shame on me :-)

Comment: Leaving this here for reference sake :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're limited to a ContentHolder couldn't you do this? (I'm using JavaScript comments in HTML...It's just easier even though it won't work :P)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    </div> //close the content div
    <div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:10px;background-color:green;";>
        CORNER
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Edit: Ok, I just realized this wouldn't work if there's content after the place holder. I'll leave it as there's a tiny chance it resolve things (probably very tiny chance)