# Break out of parent div's

Tags: css, html

When i have a `div` with `position: absolute`, and in it is another `div` with `position: absolute` the inner div will position in the frame given through the outer (wrapper) div.
Now i want to create a class (css) called error_message that positions itself exactly in the center middle of the site, indifferent from where the it is called, so i need it to break out of every div wrapped around the error_message div.. how do i do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

i had a similar problem with positioning a hoover-text centered below a floated image button list.

for me the solution was using the "fixed" value for the "position" property

```
position: fixed
```

then you can position your error message from top left of the body again.
i use another wrapper div to position all hoover texts center center.

[image]

found the solution here:

[CSS nested Div with position absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274716/css-nested-div-with-position-absolute)

the code is not the code from the picture you see, the picture is just for illustration.

stylesheet in less format (see http://lesscss.org/)

```
<style>
    .button
    {
        float: left;
        position: relative;

        a
        {
            &:hover, &:focus
            {
                .titlePos
                {
                    .title
                    {
                        display: block;
                    }
                }
            }
            .titlePos
            {
                position: fixed;
                top:50%;
                left:50%;
                width: 400px;
                margin-left: -200px;

                .title
                {
                    position:relative;
                    display: none;
                    top: 130px;
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }
        }
</style>
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="button">
                    <a href="#" >
                        <div class="buttonImage">
                            <img />
                        </div>
                        <div class="titlePos">
                            <div class="title">Button Hoover Text1</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="button">
                    <a href="#" >
                        <div class="buttonImage">
                            <img />
                        </div>
                        <div class="titlePos">
                            <div class="title">Button Hoover Text2</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="button">
                    <a href="#" >
                        <div class="buttonImage">
                            <img />
                        </div>
                        <div class="titlePos">
                            <div class="title">Button Hoover Text3</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="button">
                    <a href="#" >
                        <div class="buttonImage">
                            <img />
                        </div>
                        <div class="titlePos">
                            <div class="title">Button Hoover Text4</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try using css's `position:fixed` property, instead of `position:absolute`, for the error `div`. `position:fixed` will position an element based on the browser window, with no regard for where it falls in the DOM. If you want it to be centered in the window, regardless of window size, you could make the fixed-position div cover the entire screen (`left: 0`, `right: 0`, etc). and then text-align the error message inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why would you want that div to break out of parent div. Maybe try working on a fresh html structure for those?

http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Horizontal-Centering and http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Vertical-Centering

These should help you out!

Comment: well, the class should align it's div, but in advance it is unknown where the error class will be called ergo it could be called out of a small container aligned bottom right, so if i would simply center the error div it would appear centered - in the small bottom right container but i want it to be centered respectively to the whole webpage - independent where i call it thus independent from any possible wrappers/containers

Comment: Huh... Is there any place where we could see your code? It's kind a hard, at least for me, to image the situation over there and think of a better solution.

Comment: i have about 20 files, (html/php, no javascript) and they are all designed individually and there is a stylesheet with general classes. If in some part there is an error while getting content from the database i want to launch an error message just by displaying <div class="error_message"> $error; </div> at the place where the error occurs, and i want that div to display above all other content. i wouldn't know what code to show here

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to have a `div` break out of all parent `div`s is to have an absolute positioning on all of them, which will obviously create its own set of problems.

Why not simply have a pre-defined, hidden `div` as a direct child of the body, instead of wrapping it in the markup. You can then easily position it as you want, and insert the error messages in it with the help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). An obvious advantage to this method is that you would only have to write this `div` once, and dynamically insert the error message into it. I would even suggest having a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which allows you to easily create dialogs, both normal and modal, besides tons of other features.

---

**UPDATE**

Since JS is not allowed, an easy way to do this would indeed be displaying the div only if there was an error. So the PHP code would be ...

```
if (isset($error)) {
    echo '<div class="show_error">' . $error . '</div>';
}
```

... and the CSS class for it would be ...

```
.show_error {
    width: 400px; // error element's width
    height: 200px; // error element's height
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px; // minus half the height
    margin-left: -200px; // minus half the width
}
```

Of course, you can further style the error div as you wish, but these are needed to position it dead-center.

Hope this helps !

Comment: no javascript allowed :p, but i will create the container at the end, displaying $error, and i'll start off with $error = "" and if there's an error i'll just fill in $error

Comment: well this is about what i had, but it doesnt  'dead-center' it just centers relative to the wrapping absolute positioned div around it :/ thx for your effort though, appreciate that!

Comment: It is most important that the error div is a direct child of the `<body>`, as I mentioned in my updated answer. Basically, something like `<body><div class="show error"></div><!-- the_rest_of_your_page --></body>`. That way it wouldn't be confined to any wrappers and it would be dead-centered.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solid CSS solution here:

https://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent/

> Let’s add another parent and move the position:relative one level up
>   (or, in your context, you could maybe simply use an existing upper
>   parent).

HTML

```
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grand-parent {
  position: relative;
}
.parent {
  /*position: relative;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
  position: absolute; 
  top: -10px; 
  left: -5px;
}
```

Result:
[image]